# How can i get number of entries and column name in a unique select?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have the following table:

```
IdColumn   Name      Role   Status
  1        peter     Ope        0
  2        peter     Adm        1
  3        Jon       Ope        1
  4        Mac       Adm        1
  5        Jon       Adm        0
  6        peter     Sec        1
```

What I wanted to get is the column name and number of entries for each one in a single query.

```
select Name, Count(*) from table where Status = 1;
```

Exit example:

```
---------------
Name | Count()|
---------------
peter|  2     |
Jon  |  1     |
Mac  |  1     |
---------------
```

Comment: You know, there is a manual for this sort of thing

Comment: You are totally right.... It's really basic thing... Sorry but I didn't realise..thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic `group by` query:

```
select Name, Count(*)
from table
where Status = 1
group by Name;
```

If you are going to use SQL, you should learn the basics.  `group by` and `join` are definitely basics of the SQL language.

Comment: Thanks, as I commented to @Strawberry I didn't realise. I was so obfuscate yesterday and I couldn't see the basic thing.... it some time happen..

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` clause:

```
select Name, Count(*) from table where Status = 1 group by Name;
                                                   ^^^
                                             Add group by here
```

Answer (score 1):

### Query

```
select count(*), Name 
from table 
where status=1 
group by Name
```